# Vue router i18n redirecting to duplicate locale in route

Tags: authentication, vuejs2, vue-router, browser-history, vue-i18n

I Have a vue application with i18n and authentication via naviation guard.

My issue is that when im running:

```
 @click="pushRouteTo(`${$i18n.locale}/list/` + f.id)"  

          pushRouteTo(route) {
              try {
                  this.$router.push(route);
              } catch (error) {
                if (!(error instanceof NavigationDuplicated)) {
                    throw error;
                }
              }
          }
```

I am getting pushed to example.com/en/en/list/123 instead of example.com/en/list/123

When i place a debugger in my navigation guard it says that my to.path is "/en/en/list/123"
but i am pushing /en/list/123. How can this be?
Does it have something to do with my redirect in my router?

Here is my router.js:

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
  import Router from 'vue-router';
  import Home2 from './views/Home2.vue';
  import Login from './views/Login.vue';
  import Register from './views/Register.vue';
  import ErrorLanding from './views/ErrorLanding.vue'
  import Root from "./Root"
  import i18n, { loadLocaleMessagesAsync } from "@/i18n"
  import {
   setDocumentLang
  } from "@/util/i18n/document"

 Vue.use(Router);

 const { locale } = i18n


 export const router = new Router({
   mode: 'history',
   base: '/',
    routes: [
{
      path: '/',
      redirect: locale,
      meta: {authRequired: false},
    },
    {
      path: "/:locale",
      component: Root,
      meta: {authRequired: false},
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Home',
          path: '',
          component: Home2,
          meta: {authRequired: false},
        },
      {
        name: 'Login',
        path: 'login',
        component: Login,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: Register,
      },
      {
        path: 'lockedpage',
        name: 'lockedpage',
        webpackChunkName: "lockedpage",
        meta: {authRequired: true},
        component: () => import('./views/LockedPage.vue')
       },
       {
       path: '*',
       component: ErrorLanding,
       name: 'NotFound'
       }
     ]
   }
   ],

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  
  const { locale } = to.params
  const publicPages = [ `/`, `/${locale}`, `/${locale}/`];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');
  
  const redirect = to.path;
  
  loadLocaleMessagesAsync(locale).then(() => {
    setDocumentLang(locale)
  }).then(() => {

    if (authRequired && loggedIn === null) {
      if(to.meta.authRequired === false) {
        debugger;
        next();
      }
        else {
        debugger;
        next({ name: 'Login', query: { redirect: redirect } });
      }
      } else {
        debugger;
        next();
      }
  }) 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The root to this issue was a missing slash in my route.

```
 pushRouteTo(`${$i18n.locale}/list/` + f.id)
```

should instead be:

```
 pushRouteTo(`${/$i18n.locale}/list/` + f.id)
```

thats why it was creating a double locale.